# EnableNeo4jRepositories.sessionFactoryRef is ignored / does nothing

Tags: spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4, spring-data-neo4j-5

I'm trying to configure a Spring Boot 1.5.9 project with multiple data sources, of which some are Neo4j.
The version of spring-data-neo4j I'm using is 4.2.9.

My goal is to use a different SessionFactory for different repositories, using a different Configuration class for each.

I've got this all working with Mongo but it seems that, even though the sessionFactoryRef is available on @EnableNeo4jRepositories, it simple does not get acted upon.

Abbreviated version of my configuration, with the general concepts:

```
@org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
@EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackages = "<repo-package-name>", sessionFactoryRef = NEO4J_SESSIONFACTORY_NAME)
public class MyConfiguration {

protected static final String NEO4J_SESSIONFACTORY_NAME = "mySessionFactory";

@Bean(NEO4J_SESSIONFACTORY_NAME)
public SessionFactory mySessionFactory() {
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = ... 
    // passing entity package corresponding to repository
    return sessionFactory;
}
```

As mentioned, this construct works fine with spring-data-mongodb, however in neo4j it first starts out with an error:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

A component required a bean named 'getSessionFactory' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean named 'getSessionFactory' in your configuration.
```

Turning on debug in the logger and a look through the code led me to [SessionBeanDefinitionRegistrarPostProcessor](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-neo4j/blob/4.2.x/spring-data-neo4j/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/neo4j/repository/support/SessionBeanDefinitionRegistrarPostProcessor.java#L47), that contains the following code to get the sessionFactory:

```
private static String getSessionFactoryBeanRef(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) {
    return beanFactory.containsBeanDefinition("sessionFactory") ? "sessionFactory" : "getSessionFactory";
}
```

Hmmm... hardcoded names for a bean, no sign of customisability.

I then proceeded to name my bean twice, `@Bean("sessionFactory", NEO4J_SESSIONFACTORY_NAME)`, so the above code would pass.

The application started, but the problem is that the repositories get wired with whatever bean is called `sessionFactory`, effectively not using the `sessionFactoryRef` on the annotation.

To test this, I changed the name on the annotation to a non-existing bean and it continued to start (if I do this with the mongo-annotation, the application quits because the bean mentioned in mongoTemplateRef isn't available).

I dug a little deeper and found that, for mongo, it retrieves the bean reference in [this class](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/blob/master/spring-data-mongodb/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/mongodb/repository/config/MongoRepositoryConfigurationExtension.java#L118). The [equivalent neo4j implementation](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-neo4j/blob/4.2.x/spring-data-neo4j/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/neo4j/repository/config/Neo4jRepositoryConfigurationExtension.java#L120) has no such thing. It could of course be an implementation detail but I wasn't able to find any reference to the `sessionFactoryRef` attribute other than the annotation and the xml-schema.

There are also [other](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-neo4j/blob/master/spring-data-neo4j/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/neo4j/repository/config/Neo4jMappingContextFactoryBean.java#L60) places in the config classes that expect only one SessionFactory to be available.

So, in short, it seems to me that `EnableNeo4jRepositories.sessionFactoryRef` has no implementation and therefore simple doesn't do anything. 
As a result, with the current code a single bean "sessionFactory" must be present and all repositories will be wired with this bean, regardless of the value of sessionFactoryRef.

Anybody else with a similar experience or any idea how to file a bug for this?

Comment: You are right, this is a bug or missing feature. Please file a issue here https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAGRAPH/

Comment: done: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAGRAPH-1068